# DateTimeException: Conflict found

Tags: java, datetime

Здравствуйте. Имеется такой форматор:

```
DateTimeFormatter DATE_TIME_FORMATTER = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.A");
```

При попытке парсинга строки: '2015-12-15 09:41:51.0', выбрасывает исключение:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2015-12-15 09:41:51.0' could not be parsed: Conflict found: HourOfDay 9 differs from HourOfDay 0 while resolving  SecondOfDay
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.createError(DateTimeFormatter.java:1920)
    at java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter.parse(DateTimeFormatter.java:1855)
    at java.time.LocalDateTime.parse(LocalDateTime.java:492)
```

В чём может быть проблема?

Comment: Я бы проверил шаблон. SecondOfDay - подозрительно. Что это такое? Сколько секунд прошло с начала дня? Зачем это нужно? Может формат заставляет распознать SecondOfDay, которого в строке и близко нет.

Comment: @Sergey проверил, https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html тут вообще ни слова про SecondOfDay.

Comment: Вот что там сказано `A   -    milli-of-day` Наверное в этом всё дело. Надо `S   -    fraction-of-second`, я считаю. `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S`

Comment: @Sergey ой какая глупая ошибка. Спасибо большое.